# Using node.js libraries on front-end

Tags: node.js

How can I use the 'request' node.js module on the front-end?

normally I would retrieve it like so:

```
var request = require('request');
```

but this is not possible on the front-end since require is not recognized.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use node modules in the browser you can use a library called [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)  . This allows you to work with the common module pattern as well as the you can use this package [browser-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request) to get the features of request module